# Почему надо вызывать два раза queryset при создании paginator в Django?

Tags: python, django

**views**

```
class OrdersHomeView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'orders/orders_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'orders'
​
​
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Orders.objects.get(name='some') # **<< получаю объекты**
​
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)    
        list_orders = Orders.objects.get(name='some')  # << **вызываю второй раз те же объекты**
        paginator = Paginator(list_orders, self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            orders_page = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            page = 1
            orders_page = paginator.page(page)
        except EmptyPage:
            orders_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return context
```

как получать объекты один раз? запихнуть пагинатор в get_queryset?

Comment: а зачем вы задаете метод с получением query_set, если не используете его?

Comment: @strawdog  это определение метода, который вызывается из базового класса, и это как раз нормально. А вот зачем вручную создается Paginator и какая цель переопредиления `get_context_data` для меня загадка. Нужно объяснить, чем стандартное поведение `ListView` с заданым `paginate_by`, который включает механизм разбивки на страницы, не устраивает.

Comment: Насчёт пагинатора не знаю, но по крайней мере ведь никто не запрещает написать `list_orders = self.get_queryset()` наверное?

Comment: Но вообще свой пагинатор можно задать в методе [paginate_queryset](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/views/generic/list.py#L53) судя по всему

Comment: @andreymal `list_orders = self.get_queryset()` так получается я так же вызываю два раза? один раз при определении метода, второй раз в `get_cotext_data`?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA дело в том, что мне надо забрать queryset только текущей страницы и отправить  в другую функцию, а не все выбранные объекты. Я привел пример укороченного кода для удобство восприятия. А так то да, тут это выглядит лишним, извиняюсь

Comment: @andreymal разве я не задаю `paginate_queryset` таким образом? `paginator = Paginator(list_orders, self.paginate_by)`

Comment: Вы таким образом создаёте просто локальную переменную внутри функции, которая будет уничтожена после завершения работы функции. Аналогично объект `orders_page` тоже будет уничтожен, потому что нигде не используется

Comment: @andreymal я пытаюсь оптимизировать обращения к базе, потому что база может быть большая и два обращения к ней могут занимать много времени. я правильно понял, что при втором вызове get_queryset(), я получаю только указатель на результат первого вызов? или вы имеете ввиду, что переменная очищается и не занимает место в памяти?

Comment: Вам нужно описать изначальную задачу. "не делать два запроса" - это не задача, это следствие неправильного решения исходной задачи. Об исходной задаче я могу только догадываться, нужно бы ее описать. Похоже вам нужно до того как рендерится страница воспользоваться результатом (вы пишете "страницу отправить в функцию"). В зависимости от того, что делает функция (нельзя ли это перенести в запрос к БД, т.е. в queryset?), как используется результат (добавляется в контекст?) ответ может быть разным.